# error in passing variables in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, parameters

I am trying to pass variables from one jsp page to another and I am retrieving it through

```
s=request.getParameter("itemId");
```

The value of variable I am passing is :

```
<CAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf+nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>
```

when I pass my page address lokks likes this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Mazil-1.1.0/jsp/final.jsp?itemId=<CCAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf+nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>
```

But when I print this value on final.jsp it prints:

```
<CAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>
```

It replaces **'+' by space** .I don't know why it does that and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use it this way:

```
String encodedItemId =  URLEncoder.encode("<CAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf+nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>","UTF-8");
```

And then submit url as:

```
http://localhost:8080/Mazil-1.1.0/jsp/final.jsp?itemId=encodedItemId
```

Then to retrieve the actual Item Id do as follow:

```
String decodedItemId = URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter(itemId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace plus sign with `%2B` before sending in URL.

You also can put it as an attribute in request like this

`request.setAttribute("itemId","<CAAD0KRhXaJ5FAuOxR760HBzgaD-_JyXoVAymeQf+nQdCawEgGA@mail.gmail.com>");` in sender jsp.

And get in receiver jsp using `request.setAttribute("itemId");`

Comment: yeah I can always do that but there must be some othe solution as well!!

Comment: But if there is constraints like I will send value a if flag=0 and b if flag=1,c if flag=2,then in that case I cannot use set attribute.

Comment: You can set it as an attribute in those conditions also..accordingly you need to handle it in receiving JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Put your value into session and than retrieve it whenever you need. Using urls for it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter names and values speciﬁed should be left unencoded by the
page author. The JSP container must encode the parameter names and values
using the character encoding from the request object when necessary. For
example, if the container chooses to append the parameters to the URL in the
dispatchedrequest,boththenamesandvaluesmustbeencodedasperthecontent
typeapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded in the HTML speciﬁcation.